# Excel VBA Object required error when populating ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dropdown

I am getting the following error --

Run-time error '424' : Object required

Here is the code where I am getting the error message. The line where the error appears has been highlighted with ****

```
    Sub LoadDropdown_Click()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String
Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation
Dim vaData As Variant
Dim k As Long

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

cnt.connectionString = Module1.GetConnectionString
stSQL = "EXEC dbo.GetData"


With cnt
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient 'Necesary for creating disconnected recordset.
    .Open stConn 'Open connection.
     'Instantiate the Recordsetobject and execute the SQL-state.
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With

With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset.
    k = .Fields.Count
     'Populate the array with the whole recordset.
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

 'Close the connection.
cnt.Close

 'Manipulate the Listbox's properties and show the form.
With ComboBox21
        .Clear       ' **** the error comes at this line since ComboBox21 is empty ******
        .BoundColumn = k
        .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
        .ListIndex = -1

End With

Dim i As Integer

 'Release objects from memory.
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnt = Nothing


    End Sub
```

These are the things I have veified --

1. The ComboBox actually exists in Sheet1, called Priorities. [See this screenshot showing that Sheet1 contains a Combobox called ComboBox21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0jSJ.png)
2. The below function, LoadDropdown_Click is present in Sheet1. [See this screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejoen.png)
3. This code works when running from certain machines. It used to work on my machine earlier, but now I am getting this error suddenly without having made any changes to the code or the environment.
4. I tried changing ComboBox21 to Sheet1.ComboBox21, but I got a compile error - Method or Data member not found.

It will be great if someone can help!

Comment: Try `Sheet1.ComboBox21`

Comment: "Object Required" in this situation indicates two things: 1) you're not using `Option Explicit`, and 2) `ComboBox21` apparently isn't in-scope, try qualifying it like @RobinMackenzie suggested. Also, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and declare all your variables.

Comment: Also I'd strongly recommend you rename your control to `PrioritySelection` or something similarly meaningful. `ComboBox21` means nothing.

Comment: When I change it to Sheet1.ComboBox21, then I get a compile error - Method or Data member not found

Answer (score 0):

Please change  your code:

```
 With ComboBox21
            .Clear       ' **** the error comes at this line since ComboBox21 is empty ******
            .BoundColumn = k
            .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
            .ListIndex = -1

    End With

'With the below:

     Sheet1.ComboBox21.Clear

With Sheet1.ComboBox21
        .BoundColumn = k
        .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
        .ListIndex = -1
End With
```

Comment: As mentioned in point 4 in my original post, when I replace with Sheet1.ComboBox21, then I get a compile error - Method or Data member not found

Comment: i have made this change and it runs with no issue.

Comment: Like I mentioned in point 3 in my original post, this works fine on some machines, but not on the one I am having issue.

Comment: try to reinstall your excel!!

Answer (score -2):

Basically, you just add "On Error Resume Next" to avoid those annoying error messages popping up and then add "Err.Clear" to clear the error flag just in case.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
     On Error Resume Next
     ComboBox5.List = Sheets("Data").Range("B1:B6").Value
     Err.Clear
End Sub
```

***NOTE: This is probably not the right way of doing things but at least it works on my end***